# Gulp: How to setup an automated src & dist folder structure?

Tags: gulp, dependencies, structure, directory

Is there a best practice or common task(s) that people use to separate their source code and minified code? I don't want to have to re-minify and concatenate a file manually every time I edit it in the `src/` directory.

Apologies if this is an extremely obvious answer, but I cannot seem to find any good Gulp tutorials on folder structure dependency.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I don't want to have to re-minify and concatenate a file manually every time I edit it in the src/ directory." You shouldn't have to unless you're going to deploy to production... are you using `gulp-watch' at all?

Comment: @Barryman9000 i am not, no. i looked into a different package, but it seems to be a little clumsy to use and doesnt quite do what i want. I will check out gulp-watch tho, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One common practice is to have a `dev` task that runs [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) when you're working on something. This task (probably) shouldn't minify or run any other production type tasks. Then when you're ready to deploy you run your `prod` task which will minify and add cache busting, whatever you need (without gulp-watch).

In terms of folder structure you can have a /src and /dest directory if you'd like. It keeps things clean in your src directory and you can clean/delete the entire contents of the /dest directory because you know those are all generated files.

Comment: Hey thanks man, this sounds like a pretty good way to do it. I will try it out and report back with any questions.